# WinForm MdiControl Child Titlebar Styling

Tags: winforms, mdi, titlebar

We have a legacy WinForms application which has an odd issue with styling.

I have a main WinForm which has IsMdiContainer set to true.  I have a child form and set it's MdiParent property to the main WinForm.  Everything works as expected, except the title bar of the child form has reverted to the old XP\Vista title bar?

The main form title bar looks correct (windows 11 style) and if I just launch the child form without setting the MdiParent property, the title bar looks the same (windows 11 style), but setting the MdiParent property seems to be somehow modifying the title bar/control button styles.

Anybody seen anything like this before, or any idea why the child styles are showing an older Windows styling?  I recently looked into styling the title bar and it seemed it wasn't very straight forward, so I can't just manually change it back to look like the other title bars.

[image]

[image]